Why is my angular two-way binding performing only one-way binding?
A partial of my form is shown below. When data is entered, the data is bind to the object checkoutData in the component. The saveDataToStore method then transmits the data to the redux store. The function called in redux store saves a copy of the data to localStorage. This is working as expected.
<form #checkoutForm="ngForm">
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12 col-lg-8">
           <section>
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col">
                    <label class="form-label">First Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control fw-bold" type="text"
                        id="firstName"
                        [(ngModel)]="checkoutData?.deliveryAddress.firstName" required #firstName="ngModel"
                        (change)="saveToDataStore()"
                        (keyup)="validateInput('firstName', checkoutData.deliveryAddress.firstName)"
                        >

                    <div *ngIf="validation.firstName === false"
                        class="alert"
                      >
                        First Name is required
                     </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                    <label class="form-label">Last Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control fw-bold" type="text"
                        [(ngModel)]="checkoutData?.deliveryAddress.lastName" required #lastName="ngModel"
                        (change)="saveToDataStore()"
                        (keyup)="validateInput('lastName', checkoutData.deliveryAddress.lastName)">

                    <div *ngIf="validation.lastName === false"
                        class="alert"
                      >
                        last Name is required
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col">
                    <label class="form-label">Phone Number</label>
                    <input class="form-control fw-bold" type="phone"
                        [(ngModel)]="checkoutData?.deliveryAddress.phone" required #phone="ngModel"
                        (change)="saveToDataStore()"
                        (keyup)="validateInput('phone', checkoutData.deliveryAddress.phone)">

                    <div *ngIf="validation.phone === false"
                        class="alert"
                      >
                        Phone is required
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col">
                    <label class="form-label">Delivery Address</label>
                    <input class="form-control fw-bold" type="text"
                        [(ngModel)]="checkoutData?.deliveryAddress.address1" required #address1="ngModel"
                        (keyup)="validateInput('address1', checkoutData.deliveryAddress.address1)"
                        (change)="saveToDataStore()">

                    <div *ngIf="validation.address1 === false"
                        class="alert"
                      >
                        Address is required
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col">
                    <label class="form-label">Delivery Address Line 2 (Optional)</label>
                    <input class="form-control fw-bold" type="text"
                        [(ngModel)]="checkoutData?.deliveryAddress.address2" (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-1"
                            [(ngModel)]="checkoutData?.deliveryAddress.useAsBillingAddress"
                            (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Use as Billing
                            Address</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           </section>

           <section>
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="formCheck-2"
                            name="paymentMethod" value="PayPal"
                            [(ngModel)]="checkoutData?.paymentMethod.paymentType"
                            (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2"
                            style="font-style: italic;">PayPal</label>
                    </div>
                    <div cl ass="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="formCheck-3"
                            name="paymentMethod" value="Credit Card"
                            [(ngModel)]="checkoutData?.paymentMethod.paymentType"
                            (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-3">Credit Card</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text ps-0">
                            <i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt" style="font-size: 25px;"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input class="form-control fw-bold" type="text" required
                            [(ngModel)]="checkoutData?.paymentMethod.cardNumber"
                            #cardNumber="ngModel" 
                            (change)="saveToDataStore()"
                            (keyup)="validateInput('cardNumber', checkoutData.paymentMethod.cardNumber)"
                            placeholder="Enter credit card number">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary d-none" type="button">Button</button>
                    </div>

                    <div *ngIf="validation.cardNumber === false"
                        class="alert"
                      >
                        Card Number is required
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col col-12 col-lg-4">
                    <small>Expiration Month</small>
                    <select class="form-select fw-bold"
                        [(ngModel)]="checkoutData?.paymentMethod.expMonth" #expMonth="ngModel"
                        (change)="validateInput('expMonth', checkoutData.paymentMethod.expMonth)"
                        (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                        <optgroup label="Month">
                            <option *ngFor="let expMonth of expirationMonths"> {{expMonth}}
                            </option>
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>

                    <div *ngIf="validation.expMonth === false"
                        class="alert"
                      >
                        Expiration Month is required
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-12 col-lg-4">
                    <small>Expiration Year</small>
                    <select class="form-select fw-bold" readonly=""
                        [(ngModel)]="checkoutData?.paymentMethod.expYear" #expYear="ngModel"
                        (change)="validateInput('expYear', checkoutData.paymentMethod.expYear)"
                        (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                        <optgroup label="Year">
                            <option *ngFor="let expYear of expirationYears">
                                {{expYear}}
                            </option>
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>

                    <div *ngIf="validation.expYear === false"
                        class="alert"
                      >
                        Expiration Year is required
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-12 col-lg-4">
                    <small>CVV (on back)</small>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text ps-0">
                            <i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt" style="font-size: 25px;"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input class="form-control fw-bold" type="text" maxlength="3"
                            [(ngModel)]="checkoutData?.paymentMethod.CVV" #CVV="ngModel"
                            (keyup)="validateInput('CVV', checkoutData.paymentMethod.CVV)"
                            (change)="saveToDataStore()" placeholder="Enter CVV">

                        <button class="btn btn-primary d-none" type="button">Button</button>
                    </div>

                    <div *ngIf="validation.CVV === false"
                        class="alert"
                      >
                        CVV is required

                        <div *ngIf="checkoutData?.paymentMethod.CVV.length < 3"
                            class="alert"
                        >
                            CVV must be 3 characters
                        </div>
                     </div>       
                </div>
                <div class="col col-12 mt-4">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-4">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-1"
                            [(ngModel)]="checkoutData?.paymentMethod.defaultCreditCard"
                            (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-4"
                            style="font-size: 13px;">Save as my default credit card</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           </section>
        </div>

        <div class="col col-12 col-md-4">
            <app-order-summary></app-order-summary>

            <section class="mt-5">
                <button class="btn btn-primary w-100 primary-button" type="submit" (click)="placeOrder()"
                [disabled]="!validationsChecked()"
                    style="font-size: 20px;font-weight: bold;">Place
                    Order</button>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

The saveDataToStore function:
public saveToDataStore = () => {
this.store.dispatch(storeCheckoutData({checkoutData: this.checkoutData}))

}
The initial state of checkoutData in redux store:
checkoutData: {
    deliveryAddress: {
        firstName: null,
        lastName: null,
        phone: null,
        address1: null,
        address2: null,
        useAsBillingAddress: null,
    },
    applianceDelivery: {
        deliveryDate: null,
        specialInstructions: null,
    },
    paymentMethod: {
        paymentType: 'Credit Card',
        cardNumber: null,
        expMonth: null,
        expYear: null,
        CVV: null,
        defaultCreditCard: null,
    }
},

The storeCheckoutData function in redux:
on(storeCheckoutData, (state, action) => {
    console.log('CheckoutReducers.checkoutData', action.checkoutData)

    state = {
        ...state,    
        checkoutData: action.checkoutData
      };
    
      saveStateToLocalStorage(state);

    return {
    ...state,            
    };
}),

All of the above work as expected. However if the user should refresh the page, all of the data in the application is lost. The intention is to bring in the data stored in localStorage and reconstruct the state of the application data before the page was refreshed.
This works as expected. This is the redux function called to restore the state of the application:
on(restoreStateFromLocalStorage, (state, action) => {  
    
    if(action.hdepot?.checkoutData) {
        state.checkoutData = action.hdepot?.checkoutData
        console.log('action.hdepot?.checkoutData', action.hdepot?.checkoutData)
    } else {
        state = initialState;
        console.log('state.checkoutData', state.checkoutData)
    }
        
    return {
      ...state
    }
  }),

The data gets to the CheckoutComponent as expected and is logged to the console. The problem is the data is not binding to the checkout page. It is not showing in the form.
Essentially, we entered data into the form, the data is bind to the component, the data is transmitted to redux, the data is stored in localStorage. However when the data is brought back to CheckoutComponent, the form is blank, the data is not shown in the form even though it is present in the component.
@Naren Per your question:
checkoutData entered:
{ "deliveryAddress": { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Clark", "phone": "617 383 3333", "address1": "40 Grandville Ave.", "address2": "London, England", "useAsBillingAddress": null }, "applianceDelivery": { "deliveryDate": "2024-08-22", "specialInstructions": null }, "paymentMethod": { "paymentType": "Credit Card", "cardNumber": "5908358532093428", "expMonth": "September", "expYear": "2024", "CVV": "666", "defaultCreditCard": true } } 

checkoutData in component returned from localStorage after page is refreshed:
{ "deliveryAddress": { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Clark", "phone": "617 383 3333", "address1": "40 Grandville Ave.", "address2": "London, England", "useAsBillingAddress": null }, "applianceDelivery": { "deliveryDate": "2024-08-22", "specialInstructions": null }, "paymentMethod": { "paymentType": "Credit Card", "cardNumber": "5908358532093428", "expMonth": "September", "expYear": "2024", "CVV": "666", "defaultCreditCard": true } } 

@Naren Below is code from the developer console. Angular seems to be commenting out a substantial part of the code for each control. The data binding part if commented out. This could be the problem.
<section _ngcontent-ng-c1013304335="">
<div _ngcontent-ng-c1013304335="" class="row mb-4">
    <div _ngcontent-ng-c1013304335="" class="col">
        <label _ngcontent-ng-c1013304335="" class="form-label">First
            Name</label><input _ngcontent-ng-c1013304335="" type="text" required=""
            class="form-control fw-bold ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
        <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-ng-c1013304335="" class="col">
        <label _ngcontent-ng-c1013304335="" class="form-label">Last
            Name</label><input _ngcontent-ng-c1013304335="" type="text" required=""
            class="form-control fw-bold ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
        <!---->
    </div>
</div>


any errors in console? could you share a screenshot of the checkoutData after doing {{checkoutData | json }} in the html

@Naren No errors in console. See the bottom of my original questions for checkoutData | json.

could you remove the ?. for ngModels [(ngModel)]="checkoutData.deliveryAddress.lastName"

I did that, I seem to be experiencing a whole different problem. The last value in the ngModel in the form is shown in every form field.  defaultCreditCard which is true is shown in every field. When I comment the entire segment out, CVV is reflected in every field.

comment out all the other controls, just use one, then remove the ?. and see if two way binding works for one control alone

With only one form control, firstName, John is shown in the firstName field. However when I uncomment the next field, lastName, Clark is shown in both the firstName and lastName fields.

@Naren The code from the developer console shows that parts of the code for each field is being commented out by angular. Take a look at the bottom of my original question.

The name="___" was not included for each input.
